# Nginx conf in an ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to migrate my EC2 server to an ElasticBeanstalk, everything is running except nginx since it lose it's conf

I'm a beginner on AWS so I tried using .platform (`.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/nginx.conf`, I've also tried  `.platform/nginx/nginx.conf` but it doesn't match `include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;` from the default nginx.conf)
with this code

```
#Elastic Beanstalk Nginx Configuration File

index index.php;
access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

location /api/ {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /api/index.php last;
    }
    location /api/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php?$query_string;
    }
}

location ~ \.php {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8081;
}
```

But since it didn't seem to work, I tried using .ebextensions with these 2 script

```
#
#   STEP 1 - Create the nginx config file
#
files:

  "/tmp/my.nginx.conf" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #Elastic Beanstalk Nginx Configuration File

      user                    nginx;
      error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
      pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;
      worker_processes        auto;
      worker_rlimit_nofile    66966;

      events {
          worker_connections  1024;
      }

      http {
          include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
          default_type  application/octet-stream;

          log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                            '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                            '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

          include       conf.d/*.conf;

          map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
              default     "upgrade";
          }

          server {
              listen        80 default_server;
              server_name   http://xxx.xxx.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/;
              index index.php;
              access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

              client_header_timeout   180;
              client_body_timeout     180;
              send_timeout            180;
              proxy_connect_timeout   180;
              proxy_read_timeout      180;
              proxy_send_timeout      180;
              keepalive_timeout       180;
              fastcgi_send_timeout    180;
              fastcgi_read_timeout    180;

              gzip                  off;
              gzip_comp_level       4;
              gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

              # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
              include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;

              location /api/ {
                  if (!-e $request_filename){
                      rewrite ^(.*)$ /api/index.php last;
                  }
                  location /api/ {
                      try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php?$query_string;
                  }
              }

              location ~ \.php {
                  include fastcgi_params;
                  try_files $uri =404;
                  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                  fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
                  fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $fastcgi_path_info;
                  fastcgi_index index.php;
                  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8081;
              }
          }
      }
```

And

```
#
#   STEP 3 - Run the script to overwrite the nginx config template.
#
container_commands:
  cp_nginx:
    command: "yes | sudo /bin/cp /tmp/my.nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
```

Am I doing something wrong

Answer (score 1):

In the end I made it works using only one file in .platform/nginx

`nginx.conf`:

```
#Elastic Beanstalk Nginx Configuration File

user                    nginx;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    66966;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    include       conf.d/*.conf;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default     "upgrade";
    }

    server {
        index index.php;
        access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

        client_header_timeout   180;
        client_body_timeout     180;
        send_timeout            180;
        proxy_connect_timeout   180;
        proxy_read_timeout      180;
        proxy_send_timeout      180;
        keepalive_timeout       180;
        fastcgi_send_timeout    180;
        fastcgi_read_timeout    180;

        gzip                  off;
        gzip_comp_level       4;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
        include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;

        location /api/ {
            if (!-e $request_filename){
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /api/index.php last;
            }
            location /api/ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php?$query_string;
            }
        }

        location ~ \.php {
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8081;
        }
    }
}
```

For the explanation, since the file somehow end up dupplicated, you must remove the `servername` and `listen` line from the `server` section
and replace any relative link with an absolute one (in my case `include fastcgi_params;` => `include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;`)